# why the following errors occurs in creation of databases?

Tags: mysql

I tried to create databases but the following error occurs?

mysql> create database sample;

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'db_cad'@'%' to database 'sample'

Comment: This looks like you don't have permission rights.

Comment: What name did you launch with? Use mysqlWorkbench to see which user has create permissions. Try root first.

Answer (score 0):

your user "db_cad" don't have rights to create table after connecting to from another machine on sample database.

using following commands you can check your rights.

```
show grants;
```